# scrollIntoView on position:sticky only working in one direction

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a navbar that scrolls (using `scroll-behaviour: smooth`) the required section of the website into view.

Tested on Chrome 112.0.5615.49 (ARM build) and Safari 16.3 it works exactly as expected on `position: relative` divs (Behaviour: http://miserylovescompanyfestival.co.uk/). Using `position: sticky` for the targeted elements results in `scrollIntoView` only working for elements later in the DOM tree than the currently visible element (Behaviour: https://theexactopposite.uk/test/index-card.html - using the menu it is possible to scroll down to 'Upcoming Shows' but not scroll back up to 'About Us' from there).

codepen for the behaviour: https://codepen.io/Nigel-Powell/pen/ZEqQLyz

I have looked at the other questions regarding `scrollIntoView` and `position: sticky` here, but none seem to have had this specific issue. How can I get `scrollIntoView` to work in both directions?

Comment: Does not appear to be specific to that function being used to scroll to the target position - removing the JavaScript, and having the links point to the sections directly using `href="#containerX"`, has the same problem.

Comment: Tested on Chrome on iOS with the same result. Also the same behaviour is displayed when scrolling into view horizontallly.

Comment: Some more information: updated the codepen https://codepen.io/Nigel-Powell/pen/ZEqQLyz with an intersectionObserver, it shows elements that can't be seen as in view. Does anyone have a workaround for this?